# How to make jquery-datatables-rails inline editable ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using jquery-datatables-rails in one of my application and displaying a grid.

In order to  make it editable I added jquery-datatables-editable-rails in my gemfile.

However, I can't find  a way to make the rows editable.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is how my coffee script file for enabling datatable looks like

```
jQuery ->
 $('#products').dataTable
   sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
   bJQueryUI: true
```

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, is there an easy way to use this in a rails app. I saw jquery-datatables-editable-rails gem, but can't find an example on how to use it.

Comment: rails will be use to fetch the data in the database, the rest will be on client side

Comment: I am attempting the same thing and I'm confused if I need both gems, jquery-datatables-rails and jquery-datatables-editable-rails.  Some example code would be awesome if anyone has done this in Rails.

Comment: @binvij did the below answer work?

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful:

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/17213/table-editing-with-best-in-place-in-ruby-on-rails

It describes how to make your datatables editable with the best_in_place gem.